# A filter page with more than one select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have my target html setup but am uncertain how I would achieve the following; simply I'd like to be able to select more than one filter option that would swap the close image with a checkbox.

I'm doing all of this in an overlay page using backbone.js.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="overlaymedia">
    <div class='media-filter'>
        <div class="media-nav" role='contentinfo'>
            <div class="media-nav media-menu-container">

                <h5 class="media-menu-heading close-overlay-btn">Media Type</h5>
                <!-- Media Type: All/Photos/Videos -->
                <div class="media-select-option media-all" data-href="">All</div>
                <div class="media-select-option media-photos" data-href="">Photos</div>
                <div class="media-select-option media-videos" data-href="">Videos</div>

                <h5 class="media-menu-heading close-overlay-btn">Sort By</h5>
                <!-- Sort By: Latest/Popular -->
                <div class="media-select-option media-latest" data-href="">Latest</div>
                <div class="media-select-option media-popular" data-href="">Popular</div>
                <div class="media-menu-bottom close-overlay-btn">
                    <div class="overlay-close-btn bottom">Close</div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jQuery:

```
$('.media-select-option').on('click', function() {

    $('overlay-close-btn').addClass('checked');

}):
```

CSS:

.overlay-close-btn:before {
        content: '×';
    }

```
.overlay-close-btn.checked:before {
    content: '✔';
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks I tried adding that script and css snippet, but it didn't work :-(

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way that I could intergrate a border around the selected fields to show which have been selected?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Rob for all of your help, going to try and build on this now.